# Responding with XML when using Grails scaffolding

Tags: java, xml, grails, jersey

I have a POJO for a legacy database and I created this scaffold for it:

```
package example

import com.example.entities.ModelView

class ModelViewController {
    static scaffold = ModelView
}
```

When I go to my browser at http://example.com:8080/example/modelView/list I see a wonderful HTML page where I get full CRUD.  It's great!

Now I want to get XML so I visited the URL http://example.com:8080/example/modelView/list.xml and it still returns HTML.

My final goal is to have Jersey code that gets the XML in a Java application like this:

```
WebTarget targetBase = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://example.com:8080/example");
targetBase.path("modelView").path("list.xml").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(new GenericType<List<ModelView>>(){});
```

So I have the code above but it gets HTML from grails instead of the XML it is requesting.

How can I get Grails to send XML?

Comment: XML Of what .Do you want xml representation of all the instances of `ModelView`

Answer (score 2):

If you want XML of all your `ModelView` instances

```
def xmllist = {
   render ModelView.list() as XML
}
```

See the below link for grails Converters references

http://grails.org/Converters+Reference

Also if you want from the same `list` action you can use as following

```
import grails.converters.XML
class ModelViewController {

def list() {
    def modelViews = ModelView.list()

    withFormat {
        html modelViews :modelViews 
        js { render "alert('hello')" }
        xml { render modelViews as XML }
    }
  }
}
```

Grails ignores the `HTTP Accept header` unless you add a `grails.mime.use.accept.header = true` setting to your `Config.groovy` file. In other words, `withFormat()` will be completely unaffected by the `Accept header` without that setting.

Comment: This works and is what I've been using, but I actually wanted to use the scaffolding so I don't have to generate all the actions for CRUD... looks like that's my best bet unless I can get the solution from @bschipp working.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to install the grails Scaffolding plugin (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) which will allow you to override the default controller and view templates that are used to generate what you describe as the 'wonderful HTML page' with full CRUD. You would then be able to add the Jersey code on an action in a controller template, and every new page you generate scaffolding for will have this action.

All the best with it.

Answer (score 0):

Grails [withFormat](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) is what are you looking for.

Do not forget to set value of `grails.mime.use.accept.header` config to to `true`

```
grails.mime.use.accept.header = true
```